# How to infere a similar function given a graph

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

I am trying to identify a function of the following graph in order to implement an animation. It doesn't need to be exactly, anything similar would do the work.

[image]

The function repeat itself as you can see in red. In green is the same but mirrored.

I am currently trying combining polinomials and trigonometric functions, if I use different ranges of those I could get something similar but it should be something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, 
consider, for example, seven cubic Bezier segments,

[image]

where the Bezier control points are

```
/* 0*/ ( 0,20),
/* 1*/ ( 6,20),
/* 2*/ ( 7,17),
/* 3*/ (11,20),
/* 4*/ (15,23),
/* 5*/ (20,30),
/* 6*/ (26,28),
/* 7*/ (32,26),
/* 8*/ (37,14),
/* 9*/ (42,13),
/*10*/ (47,12),
/*11*/ (53,21),
/*12*/ (57,22),
/*13*/ (61,23),
/*14*/ (64,17),
/*15*/ (69,20),
/*16*/ (74,23),
/*17*/ (81,34),
/*18*/ (85,29),
/*19*/ (89,24),
/*20*/ (90, 2),
/*21*/ (100,2)
```

Periodic line looks like

[image]

Comment: This is amazing!, thank you very much. One question thought, what are you using to generate the Bezier ?, I tried some web pages and they work ok but they usually allow to work with just one segment.

Comment: @user43438: 
I prefer [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)